# use a function with trim in a select with the exact number of digits after the comma

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm using a function in my select to take the max between two columns and insert it in a third.
the function is:

```
create function dbo.InlineMax(@val1 float, @val2 float)
returns float
as
begin
  if @val1 > @val2
    return @val1
  return isnull(@val2,@val1)
end
```

i used it in my select like this:

```
declare @f int
set @f = 0  --i'm doing this because i will need it later
select a, 
       b, 
       c, 
      left((dbo.InlineMax(t.b, t.c)+@f),10) as d
from #myTable t
order by someCriteria
```

data sample

```
a           b        c           d
someName1  -23.432   -84.2345   -23.4321
someName2  -30.789   3.04       3.045
```

I want the values from 'd' to always have the same size as the column from b or c. I know i'm trimming it to 10 characters and the values from 'b' and 'c' probably have a variable number of .digits . **But how to remain consistent?**

Comment: can you explain it a bit, not getting it, sorry, maybe this is easy but i can't see it now

Comment: i want the format to be variable, but in such a way in which it always fits the number of digits from b or c (depending on which of those was selected the max). If i add 0's like you said, is that a good approach?

Comment: Just `ROUND` all values to 2 places like simplest and the best.

Comment: it's very important not to lose any data. I could do that but I don't think it's the way to go. Maybe there's a better way

Comment: Floating point numbers do not have a "size" (more precisely, a "precision").  Decimals do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the good old `CASE` statement? It will be *a lot* faster than calling a function. And easier to maintain, too.

```
select
    a, 
    b, 
    c, 
    left(case when t.b > t.c then t.b else isnull(t.c, t.b) end + @f, 10) as d
from
    #myTable t
order by
    someCriteria
```

Comment: Can the case statement deal with null values? I'm not sure and that's why i chose the function path. for some values i'm comparing null with a number , so any number it finds will be copied to d

Comment: A CASE statement is an SQL expession, so, yes, of course it can handle NULL values. If any of `b` or `c` are NULL, the comparison yields NULL which will make the CASE goes into the ELSE branch. If you don't want that to happen, use `isnull()` on the comparison or the individual operands.

Comment: i don't want for the comparisson to yield NULL. If one of them are null, then the one which isn't will be outputed to d. How would you write that using isnull() as you mentioned?

Comment: If `t.b > t.c` succeeds, then `t.b` cannot be NULL. So `case when t.b > t.c then t.b` is correct in any case. Now think about the ELSE part. The real question is: What should happen if *both* values are NULL, because `isnull(t.c, t.b)` will return NULL in that case as well. You will figure it out, I am sure.

Comment: i got it now, thank you, it works. I would say better than my solution

Comment: Well, then the expression should do it as it is (the syntax error is fixed, by the way). Unless `b` is an actual `NOT NULL` column, I would be defensive and wrap the entire thing it in an `isnull()`, just to make sure that it *really* never can be null.

Comment: @viorel You could write it as `left(isnull(case when t.b > t.c then t.b else t.c end, t.b) + @f, 10) as d`, which is equivalent and maybe more readable.